# Various ways to execute a function in vim

Tags: vim

I've been doing some trial-and-error on how functions can be called, and it seems like the following is my understanding:

1. From the command line, typing in `:call MyFunction()`
2. From the command line, typing in `:call execute('call MyFunction')`, where execute essentially performs a string escape (if that's the correct term?) to pass back to the first `call` param.
3. From within a function or vim file, typing in `call MyFunction()`. In other words, each line in a vim function/file acts like the command-line.
4. From within a function or vim file, typing in `call execute('call MyFunction')`

Is that a correct understanding of the various ways to call a function? Are there any other possible ways to do it?

Comment: Is this question actually about "when and why I must use :call"?

Comment: @Matt yea, more or less. Though in one of the answers below I've seen `eval(...)` which I haven't come across before.

Comment: Do you know the difference between statements and expressions? Say in C you do simply `func();` when you mean `(void)func();` but in VimScript no expression is a statement. Roughly speaking, a statement in VimScript is `:command [expression]`. Hence `:call func()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are doing, but if you ask if there are other ways to call a function, yes, there are.

For example,

- the `eval(...)` can call another function
- `echo getline('.')` or something like this
- `:s/../\=getline(...)`
- in expr mappings
- ...

Simply put, in almost any place when a vimscript can be evaluated, a function can be called.